# Which is the correct preposition in the following sentences?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-request

> I'm disappointed ***at you.***
>
> I'm disappointed ***with you.***
>
> I'm disappointed ***in you.***
>
> I’m disappointed ***by you.***

Answer (score 1):

The [Online OXFORD Collocation Dictionary](http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=disappointed) suggest the following prepositions according to context:

> PREP. ***about*** I'm disappointed about John not coming. | ***at*** They're disappointed at the result. | ***by*** I was slightly disappointed by her attitude. | ***in*** He's disappointed in his daughter. | ***with*** We're disappointed with the new car.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disappointed%20with%2Cdisappointed%20by%2Cdisappointed%20in%2Cdisappointed%20at%2Cdisappointed%20about&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisappointed%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisappointed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisappointed%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisappointed%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisappointed%20about%3B%2Cc0://) shows the more common usages.

In your sentence, “disappointed in you” is probably the more common usage.

Comment: How about: You disappoint me.  Then go on to say how.

Comment: @CrossRoads -             It is grammatical, see usage examples here https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you%20disappoint%20me%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en